# How to give tooltip to <th> element of table in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to give tooltip to  element of table while hover the element.

```
<th id="metricsHead">Grade_Desc</th>
```

While hovering the element the tooltip should be "Grade Description"

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `title` attribute

```html
<table>
  <th id="metricsHead" title="Grade Description">Grade_Desc</th>
</table>
```

if you want to set it dynamically

```js
$('#metricsHead').attr('title', "Grade Description")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th id="metricsHead" >Grade_Desc</th>
</table>
```

Comment: I need to give tooltip dynamically

Comment: @Nimmi, Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Nimmi :  add the `title` attribute dynamically using `attr('title','value...')`

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('metricsHead').title = 'your new title';
```

other option from jquery is

```
$('#metricsHead').prop('title', 'your new title');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `title` attribute with jQuery.

```
$("#metricsHead").attr("title", "Grade Description");
```